# JavaFX Robot.createscreencapture eating memory

Tags: java, javafx, out-of-memory, screenshot, awtrobot

Hello i am creating a remote control software and when i am using Robot.createscreencapture i get outofmemory error very fast and its the only way i found to take a screenshot soo is there a way to maybe clean the memory that createscreencapture is creating? everytime i create a screenshot after 1 second it send a new one but if it says outofmemory that means its storing all the screenshots its getting into memory? soo is there a way to solve this by doing a trick or something? i did increase the max memory but it still gives outofmemory error.

This is the code piece:

```
// Capture screen
                        Robot clientrobot = new Robot();
                        Rectangle robotrectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
                        BufferedImage image = clientrobot.createScreenCapture(robotrectangle);

                        String imageStringByte = null;  
                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", bos);  
                        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();  

                        imageStringByte = Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);  

                        bos.close();

                        output.writeObject("RECEIVEDESKTOP-" + imageStringByte);
                        output.flush();
```

It says this line is the error: `BufferedImage image = clientrobot.createScreenCapture(robotrectangle);`

But once it also sayed that: ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", bos) is the error but it happened only once. Soo how can i prevent the screenshot from eating memory?

This is the error log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.getRGBPixels(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture(Unknown Source)
    at application.MainController$2.run(MainController.java:186)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can take time to capture and send the image, you might consider ensuring that until one pass has completed, another isn't allowed to start

Comment: How could i check it? i can execute it like every 1 second instead of 100 milliseconds that should be big enough delay for the server to receive the image.

Comment: Instead of `Timer`, use a `Thread`, which has minimum of a 1 second sleep

Comment: Is there a way to do this faster? like a software called TeamViewer? that receive dekstop really fast

Comment: The memory usage is still increasing! how can i remove the created scren shot or something? it keeps increasing the memory even every 3 seconds!

Comment: SOMEONE PLEASE HELP! there must be a way to remove the problem!

Comment: I did a quick test, capturing a screen shot every second for about 20 mins and while the memory usage did increase, the JVM was able to increase it's overall requirements. It run without any out of memory issues. You might consider reducing the area your are capturing, maybe focusing on the area around the mouse and monitoring it's movements and trying to capture the areas if moves through instead, as a an idea

Comment: But what if i want to see the hole screen? there must be a way to capture the screen without memory increase like mark it as a garbage and then clean it when its sent to the stream or something

Comment: Alright i did test it by capturing a screen shot every 1 second and the memory was increasing slower but it still was increasing and after 10 min it reached outofmemory point there must be a way or something to prevent this and allow it for a very long time i need it running for about 8 hours at least UPDATE: i flushed the binaryimage when sent to stream that did help a bit

Comment: I think decreasing pixel amount in the image should decrease the ram increase even more but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: I tried it using button and i think i found the problem every time the code that gets the screenshot exectute it increases ram usage by 30mb and then its good again soo all of these screenshots are increasing ram there must be a way to remove them from the memory

Comment: There was a bug report about `Robot#createScreenCapture` which was about a memory leak, but it was suppose to be fixed, you might consider having a look to see if anyone else has been effected by it as well

Comment: I am using the latest version and i am currently the only one person working on this project but looking at stackoverflow questions it seems that people do have the same issue

Comment: UPDATE: i found this post: http://www.codef.xyz/answer/should-can-i-override-the-robot-class-to-save-memory-with-repeated-screen-cap it seems that this guy in the answers section found a fix but doesnt say what it is

Comment: I kinda fixed the problem i slowed it down as much as possible and made when outofmemory error happens restart the application instantly that cleans the memory

Comment: Administrator or moderator please close this form. There will be no solution to this.